# How to set header cell borders' color of datagridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

`GridColor` property of `DataGridView` can set the color of the grid lines separating the cells of the `DataGridView`(i.e. borders of every cell).

But it can't change the grid lines' color of header cells(i.e. borders of header cells).
How can I achieve this?
Is there a property that I can use to accomplish this?

1.image of using `GridColor` property
[image: using <code>GridColor</code> property]
2.image of My requirement
[image]

As TnTinMn said, the `GridColor` property only affects cells with `CellBorderStyle= DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.Single`.
The result is like the following image.
It can't affect the grid lines seperating the header cells.

3.image of using `CellBorderStyle` property
[image]

After another try, I succeed.
4.image of using `EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false'
[image]

(**Solution**)**To summarize:**
1.Using `GridColor` to set the color of grid lines.
2.Set `CellBorderStyle`,`ColumnHeadersBorderStyle`,`RowHeadersBorderStyle` to `Single`.
3.Set `EnableHeadersVisualStyles` to `false`.

Comment: So you don't want to change the actual cell colour, just the lines that separate them? This seems like an odd thing to want to achieve?

Comment: Actually I want to set the colors of the borders in header cells.Maybe I haven't explained clearly.

Comment: IMO, It's clear what the OP is asking. If you need more details it's better to ask questions in comments instead of closing such question.

Comment: Have you tried look at the [paint event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710987/how-to-set-the-border-color-of-a-particular-header-cell-in-datagridview)?  I don't get why this was closed, I would understand if this was a duplicate.

Comment: @the_lotus I want to know whether there is a simple way to achieve this.

Comment: I'll answer as a comment since on hold.  The `GridColor` property only affects cells with `CellBorderStyl e= DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.Single`.  To change the border style of the column headers, you need to create a derived DGV control and override the [DataGridView.AdjustColumnHeaderBorderStyle Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.adjustcolumnheaderborderstyle(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) and set `dataGridViewAdvancedBorderStylePlaceholder.All = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.Single` and return `dataGridViewAdvancedBorderStylePlaceholder`

Comment: What do I need to do in order to get the question reopened?

Answer (score 2):

*Do the 3 things you listed, and then:*

4. Set `CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.Raised` - this will allow your colouring to show up in the header only, but because you've now set the body cell border to a 3D type (i.e. `raised`, `sunken` etc, not `single` or `none` etc), the body's cell will have a system default styling (likely to be grey).

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Coming in late, but if you want to keep `EnableHeadersVisualStyles = true`, you may change `AdvancedColumnHeaderBorderStyle`, `AdvancedRowHeadersBorderStyle`, `AdvancedCellBorderStyle` side properties. To solve [@niaomingjian](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39445475/11409835) example, you would need to change these as:

```
dgv.AdvancedColumnHeadersBorderStyle.Top = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
dgv.AdvancedColumnHeadersBorderStyle.Left = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
dgv.AdvancedColumnHeadersBorderStyle.Right = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.Single;
dgv.AdvancedColumnHeadersBorderStyle.Bottom = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.Single;

dgv.AdvancedCellBorderStyle.Top = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
dgv.AdvancedCellBorderStyle.Left = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
dgv.AdvancedCellBorderStyle.Right = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.Single;
dgv.AdvancedCellBorderStyle.Bottom = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.Single;

dgv.AdvancedRowHeadersBorderStyle.Top = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
dgv.AdvancedRowHeadersBorderStyle.Left = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
dgv.AdvancedRowHeadersBorderStyle.Right = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.Single;
dgv.AdvancedRowHeadersBorderStyle.Bottom = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.Single;
```

Setting `AdvancedColumnHeaderBorderStyle.All`, `AdvancedRowHeadersBorderStyle.All` or `AdvancedCellBorderStyle.All` to a single style, seems to work differently so you need to adjust every side separately to trigger such styling.